# How to store a values of multiple inputs in the state of a mapping React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck, I am trying to store inputs into my state, but I don't have lucky.

I have a page where you can create combos of foods, when you select one product you must assign a quantity to that product,

**Example:**

**Combo 20**

** Product: Pizza, Quantity: 2**

I have the following code I'm trying to add this quantity, store in any place but apparently the data overlap and in the end I end up having 3 products and only the last result of the quantity

```
state = {
    optionsProductsCount : []
}

commonChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        optionsProductsCount : {
            id : event.target.name,
            value : event.target.value
        }
    })
}

{this.state.selectedOption.map(product => (
    <div className="form-group" key={product.value}>
        <input 
            onChange={this.commonChange}
            name={product.value}
            style={{width: '60px'}} 
            type="number" min="1" step="1" title="Numbers only" 
            className="form-control" 
            required
        />
    </div>
 ))}
```

I was thinking in a lot of ways to solve, but I can't make work anyone

```
this.state.optionsProductsCount.push({
    id: event.target.name,
    value: event.target.value
})
```

When I try to do it I have duplicate data, This is because when you place a quantity and then change it the data is sent two times, and if you change again three, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to keep a unique record for each product, use dictionary instead of array for the state `optionsProductsCount`. Here is how you update it:

```
commonChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        optionsProductsCount : {
            ...this.state.optionsProductCount,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `optionsProductsCount` is an array, I guess, this is where your problem lies; you are updating your `optionsProductsCount` to a non-array object.

```
commonChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        optionsProductsCount : [
            ...this.state.optionsProductsCount,
            {
                id : event.target.name,
                value : event.target.value
            }
        ]
    })
}
```